# Changing a number upon every refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, web

How could I generate a random number every refresh using html and javascript?

I have the javascript that would generate a decimal number.

```js
 function DecimalGenerate() {
    var min = 1.03,
        max = 5.99,
        NumberResult = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

    alert(parseFloat(NumberResult).toFixed( 2 ));
};

DecimalGenerate();
```

But how could I display the actual code using html?

Comment: Did you try parseInt()?

Comment: what do you mean by `how could I display the actual code using html?`

Comment: Nevermind I solved it this is what I met by the way http://jsfiddle.net/Eos_/yyAf8/36/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/37gzc343/ @Maelstorm

Answer (score 1):

you can simply call that fucntion on JQuery.( document ).ready(). I have displayed the random generated number in text box

Html

```
<input type='text' id='text1'>
```

JQuery

```
function DecimalGenerate() {
    var min = 1.03,
        max = 5.99,
        NumberResult = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

    $('#text1').val(parseFloat(NumberResult).toFixed( 2 ));
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
DecimalGenerate();
});
```

You can check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cb4x6wL1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a button that generates a random number every time you press the button. The button triggers the function to be executed, thus generating the random number and appending it to the h3 tag of the html document.

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Generate Random Number</h1>
    <h3 id="rand"></h3>
    <button onclick="DecimalGenerate();">Random</button>
  </body>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function DecimalGenerate() {
    var min = 1.03,
        max = 5.99,
        NumberResult = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

    var rand = document.getElementById('rand');
     rand.textContent = NumberResult.toFixed( 2 );

};

DecimalGenerate();
```

Here is a link to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DlvJ5UEIRvkHqoj3kfw8?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="new">this is a number</p>
    <script>
    (function () {
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    })();
    </script>
    </body></html>
```

it is a self invoking function and for each time we refresh the window it cahanges it's value randomly between 0 to 1 and multiplying it by 100 and then use floor function give us value between 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer worked for me but how to remove . from result (1752115.32)

JQuery

```
function DecimalGenerate() {
    var min = 1.03,
        max = 5.99,
        NumberResult = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

    $('#text1').val(parseFloat(NumberResult).toFixed( 2 ));
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
DecimalGenerate();
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.